# Using jQuery to modify the name of a CSS class - Not working on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, classname

I have the following code (using XSLT/HTML)

```
<div class="{@ClassName} modify""><img src="{substring-before(@Image, ', ')}"/></div>
```

The "ClassName" is being through dynamically through a CMS, which when there are two options selected, they are segregated by a bunch of other characters. As a result you end up with something similar to this:

```
;#class1;#class2;#
```

What I'm trying to do is modify the class names based on what they are currently set to. I written the following code, which when entered into the browsers console window, works an absolute charm. However, when added to the actual page, it doesn't take effect. I'm wondering if it's a priority thing or something else:

```
$('.modify').each(function(){
var newPrimeItem= "primary item";
var newItem = "item";
if ( $(this).attr('class') == ";#primary;#item;# modify") { $(this).attr('class', newPrimeItem);}
if ( $(this).attr('class') == ";#item;# modify") { $(this).attr('class', newItem );}    
});
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is that code wrapped in a DOM ready or placed at the end of the document?

Comment: Do you have a class called ";#primary;#item;# modify" ?

Comment: that is a messy classname you have. You can check the rules here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: It's in the document ready. Bob, as I said, this is generated from a Content management system, hence why i'm trying to modify it and make it cleaner. Sergio, yes, I do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to trigger a function on page load, you need to wrap it in a DOM ready.

Here is a tutorial on [DOM ready for jquery](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Code to be executed on page load.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The class names in your html contain special characters that is the reason why jquery didn't find the selector. Source [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) site.

> **To use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar")**

```
$('.modify').each(function(){
    var newPrimeItem= "primary item";
    var newItem = "item";

    var me = $(this);
    //remember that classes are separated with space
    if (me.hasClass("\\;\\#primary\\;\\#item\\;\\#") && me.hasClass("modify"))
    { 
        me.attr('class', newPrimeItem);
    }
    if ( me.hasClass("\\;\\#item\\;\\#")  && me.hasClass("modify") ) 
    { 
        me.attr('class', newItem );
    }    
});
```

[FIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/RmZ8S/)

Comment: Thanks Bob - Appreciated. The code started working. Unfortunately it was a terrible mistake of a colleague stripping it out of the document ready and not calling the function. Otherwise it works fine. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: It often happens for collaboration works. Glad it worked now.